# Obviar getElementById() ¿Buena practica?

Tags: javascript

No lo lei en ningun lado, lo descubrí por accidente cuando programaba. Me he dado cuenta que cuando tienes un elemento con cierto id, por ejemplo `element`, javascript automáticamente crea una variable que almacena el elemento, y el nombre de la variable es el mismo que el nombre del id del elemento. El elemento automáticamente se almacena así `element = document.getElementById('element')` sin que yo lo escriba.

```js
element.style.cssText="background-color: black; width:100%; height:300px";
```

```html
<div id='element'></div>
```

Vean que sin escribir `document.getElementById('element')` puedo acceder a sus propiedades.

¿Obviar escribir `document.getElementById()` se puede considerar buena practica o no?

Comment: Fue diseñado para obtener un elemento HTML específico, si lo obvias, estás evitando una característica importante del lenguaje. ¿De qué forma obtendrías un elemento HTML?

Comment: @HéctorM. El elemento ya se obtiene automaticamente, solo tengo que escribir la variable igual al nombre del Id y ya ingresé al elemento, sin escribir ``getElementbyId()``

Comment: "El elemento automáticamente se almacena así `element = document.getElementById('element')` sin que yo lo escriba": ¿dónde y cómo estás viendo lo que estás mencionando?

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita más detalles y aclaraciones, el `getElementById()` sirve para capturar un elemento de tu HTML, ¿Porqué obviarlo?...

Comment: Ya añadi un snippet para que vean el efecto

Comment: Creo que la pregunta debe mejorar mensionando el reemplazo del que se está obviando. En este caso, si se obvia `document.getElementById("objeto")`, se debe usar directamente `objeto.addEventListener()` ó `objeto.style.color = "red"` ??? Y si se puede obviar; pero solo en algunos casos

Comment: Esto no es algo nuevo, si el elemento existe en el HTML como una ID, entonces si se puede usar en javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El comportamiento que usted describe se llama [named access on the window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) y está presente (como puede ver en el enlace) en la especificación de HTML

No obstante, no es buena práctica hacer uso de ello, porque el `ID` de un elemento se guarda como variable global, si quizás se guardara como constate podría ser aceptable.

El problema es que justamente su calidad de variable permite pisar el valor.

Por ejemplo

Esto funciona:

```js
console.log(ventas);
console.log(document.getElementById("ventas"));
console.log(document.getElementById("ventas").value);
```

```html
<input id="ventas" value="3">
```

**Ahora lo pisamos y ya no funciona**

```js
let ventas = "HOLA";
console.log(ventas);
console.log(document.getElementById("ventas"));
console.log(document.getElementById("ventas").value);
```

```html
<input id="ventas" value="3">
```

Uno podría pensar que esto se soluciona colocando nombres distintos y teniendo mucho cuidado. Y quizás podría funcionar en algo pequeño, pero en una aplicación algo más grande sería un riesgo

Siempre se debe pensar en el peor de los casos, no se deben asumir riesgos innecesarios y evitar errores no forzados. Y es por esto que no vale la pena usar el ID como variable global

Si bien existen nombres (ID's) infinitos, la tendencia es a repetirlos, porque estos ID's se nombran con un significado semántico, a más de alguno nos ha pasado pensar en *¿Como diablos nombro esta variable?*, ahí no pareciera que son tan infinitos.

Hay que tener en cuenta que javascript al ser un lenguaje interpretado los errores aparecen al ejecutar y probar, no así en lenguajes compilados que muchos de los errores aparecen en tiempo de compilación (y en los más modernos IDE aparecen incluso antes). Además, el no ser fuertemente tipado agrega otro ingrediente que dificulta la depuración, ya que los IDE no son capaces de alertar con prontitud el problema, por lo menos yo no conozco alguno que arroje al menos un warning que diga que esa variable ya existe como ID de un elemento.

Al menos se dé un caso donde esto aconteció. El error no fue detectado hasta entrado en producción, y los usuarios solo declaraban un comportamiento anómalo en algunas situaciones. Imagina lo difícil que es encontrar un problema, si solo te dicen "a veces no guarda el dato" y tú no eres capaz de reproducir el mismo error.
Y todo se podría haber evitado al usar `document.getElementById`, una tontera la verdad, pero al cliente no le pareció tan tonto.

Se que es tentador usar la otra alternativa, sobre todo porque `document.getElementById` es excesivamente largo, es que se le fue de las manos a los creadores. Yo habitualmente lo que hago es crear mi propia función, ejemplo:

```js
const Getel = e => document.getElementById(e);

console.log(Getel("input").value);
```

```html
<input id="input" value="asd">
```

Por ultimo señalar que `document.getElementById` es increiblemente rápido e incluso (según algunas de pruebas de usuarios en la red) es más rápido que usar `named access on the window object`